# Why does this transitive closure of z3 produce different results?

Tags: z3, z3py, transitive-closure

I am running the following program about transitive closure of z3:

```
from z3 import *

def main():
    A = DeclareSort('A')
    R = Function('R', A, A, BoolSort())
    TC_R = TransitiveClosure(R)
    # TRC_R = TransitiveReflexiveClosure(R)
    s = Solver()
    a, b, c = Consts('a b c', A)
    s.add(R(a, b))
    s.add(R(b, c))
    s.add(Not(TC_R(a, c)))

    print(s.check())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output the above program on my computer is 'sat'. However, the documents says it should produce 'unsat' and I agree with this  [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-transitive-closure](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-transitive-closure). But I don't know why my output is different? Here is the screenshot. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. Please report it at: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: Thanks. I have reported it.